# Support for Control-flow Enforcement Technology (CET)?

Tags: linux, cpu

I'm trying to setup CI tests against control flow technology to ensure our inline ASM performs as expected with shadow stacks. The feature is called [Control-flow Enforcement Technology (CET)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/4d/2a/control-flow-enforcement-technology-preview.pdf) on Intel processors, and GCC offers the options to enable it via [`-fcf-protection=full`, `-mcet`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) and friends.

I performed a quick test using Fedora 26/GCC 7.2 on a 7th gen Core i5. It resulted in a failure, which was not surprising:

```
$ CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fcf-protection=full -mcet" make
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fcf-protection=full’; did you mean ‘-fstack-protector-all’?
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mcet’; did you mean ‘-maes’?
make: *** [GNUmakefile:1057: cryptlib.o] Error 1
```

I visited [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43539/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and I did not see `cet` or `ibt` flags.

My first question is, what Intel processors support CET?

My second question is, does CET require kernel support? If so, what Linux kernels support it?

Comment: What I'm curious about is if this is deployed, will individual processes on a system that supports it be able to opt out of it or will it be that `-fcf-protection=none` => your program doesn't run?

Answer (score 3):

> My first question is, what Intel processors support CET?

As of October 20th 2017 there are no Intel processors currently being sold that support it.

> Intel hasn't officially commented on when CET will be featured in new
> CPUs for control flow integrity protection, but given the timing of
> the GCC work, hopefully we'll see it in place for Cannonlake or worst
> case Ice lake.

[Control-Flow Enforcement Technology Begins To Land In GCC 8](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-CET-GCC-8-Landing)

> I performed a quick test using Fedora 26/GCC 7.2 on a 7th gen Core i5.
> It resulted in a failure, which was not surprising:

You need to use a version of GCC that supports this feature in order to use it within your program.  This means you will want to use GCC 8.1 once it is released.  It is unlikely kernel support will be required, but considering no processors on the market currently support, it is nearly impossible to predict what the requirements will be exactly.

However, I don't see any indication kernel support would be required, since these instructions that GCC would be using are platform independent.  I would not be shocked if kernels added features, that used these instructions to their APIs in the future.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. So what do you wish to achieve with your bounty?

Comment: -1 for the link to a charlatan like Steve Gibson...

Comment: @forest - I agree Steve Gibson is a hack, who had made money, selling snake oil to computer users for decades.  However, even snake oil salesmen, sometimes have interesting things to say.